# Can Lean simp arguments be ordered?

Tags: lean, tactic

I want to simplify the expression `0 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 0` using `simp only [mul_zero, zero_mul]`. I would like `mul_zero` to fire first, so that the entire expression is simplified to zero in only one step. If `mul_zero` fires first, I would expect the simplification process to take 4 steps, due to there being one step to eliminate each `1`.

Is there a way I can tell Lean to prioritize which simplification lemma to try first?

Comment: My understanding is that `simp` operates by deeply entering expressions, seeing what applies, then working outwards. That means it'll see the `0 * 1` first no matter what. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using mathlib's `simp_rw`, you can order your lemmas:

```
example (a : nat) : a + 0 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 0 = a := by simp_rw [mul_zero, add_zero]
```

`simp_rw [lemma1, lemma2]` does the hand-waved equivalent of `simp only [lemma1], simp only [lemma2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Lean's `simp` arguments are already ordered:

```
def a := 0
def b := 0
def c := 0
def f : ℕ → ℕ := default
@[simp] lemma k (x) : f x = b := rfl
@[simp] lemma l : f b = c := rfl

example : f (f a) = c := by simp only [k, l]
example : f (f a) = c := by simp only [l, k] -- failure!
```